# Почти половина опрошенных призналась, или признались?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Какой вариант здесь предпочтительнее? Влияет ли на выбор числа глагола "почти" перед "половина" (поскольку раз "почти", значит, не совсем половина)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выбираем вариант: Почти половина опрошенных **признались.**
**Это согласование по смыслу**, которое в современном языке используются всё чаще, причем в различных стилях речи.

Также выбор мн. числа в данном случае подчеркивает  **индивидуальное**  (а не собирательное) **действие** каждого участника.